# Linking SQL 2005 tables in Access (Client file) and distributing to users

Tags: sql-server-2005, ms-access-2007

I've used the Access 2007 upsizing wizard to move my files to a SQL server.  A problem I'm experiencing now is that when I try to link the tables in either Excel or Access, it requires me to create a DSN or a machine data source connection.  In either case, when I do this, it makes the connection only useful on the current PC.

What I'm trying to do is create an access file and an excel file, both of which link to the newly upsized tables on the sql server, which I can distribute to users across the network (let's assume they all have sufficient user rights on the SQL server to read data).

Any suggestions?

Chuck

Comment: Whoever voted this as belonging on SuperUser is an idiot. Just because it's an Access question doesn't mean it doesn't belong on SO -- this is a programming/database question and quite reasonably belongs here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Doug Steele's code to convert your DSN's to DSN-less connect strings:

http://www.accessmvp.com/DJSteele/DSNLessLinks.html